# How to add div dynamically inside a div using jQuery. It should display first also?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic, html

I have a parent div like this.

```
<div id='parent'>
   <div id='child_1'>........</div>
   <div id='child_2'>........</div>
   <div id='child_3'>........</div>
   <div id='child_4'>........</div>
</div>
```

I want to add one div like this:

```
<div id='page_number'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>
```

Inside parent div I'm using append to do like that.

```
$("#parent").append("<div id='page_number'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>");
```

But its comming after child_4 th div. But I need to display it just below of child_1. 
It should come like this

```
<div id='parent'>
   <div id='page_number'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>
   <div id='child_1'>........</div>
   <div id='child_2'>........</div>
   <div id='child_3'>........</div>
   <div id='child_4'>........</div>
</div>
```

How can I do like this.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

make use of jquery function [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) : Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements

```
$('Selector ').prepend($('<div> new div </div>'));
```

Answer (score 11):

use prepend instead of append:

```
$("#parent").prepend("<div id='page_number'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$("#parent").prepend(
    "<div id='page_number'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>");
```

Answer (score 5):

See `$("#parent").append("")` adds your div at the end of the selected element....
if you want to add your `divs` as the first child of the parent, try prepend...

```
$("#parent").prepend("");
```

Answer (score 2):

As well as using the .prepend() command mentioned by the other answers you can also use the [.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) command:

```
$("<div id='page_number'>You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>").prependTo("#parent");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "prepend":

[prepend Api](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$("#parent").prepend(Your HTML)
```